# How do I render an animated 3D scene to h.264 stream?

Tags: linux, 3d, rendering

I'm working on a computer vision application and need a way to provide some automated testing. I can't use a simple (static) video stream because part of the testing has to involve changing the camera angle and zoom. So I figured that a good way to go about it would be to simulate the camera in a 3D animation, so that the camera can be moved around while the animation is running and still provide a visually consistent 2D video stream.

I know I can code all of this with OpenGL or Unity3D or whatever, but I am by no means a 3D programming expert and it looks like a lot of learning curve for something that I just need as a testbed. I'm hoping that someone can help me find the shortcut to implementing this - in fact if there is a pre-built tool that does it, I'd be happy to use it (I haven't found one). Here are the general constraints:

- Loads a 3D animation from a file (I'm guessing FBX format but anything is fine)
- Begins rendering the animation
- Outputs the video to a h.264 stream - doesn't matter if this is to memory, to a file, streamed over network, whatever, I can wire it up somehow
- Allows real-time changes to the camera location and orientation - again, doesn't matter what mechanism is used to make these changes

Is there a simple way to do this, or do I have to bite the bullet and become an OpenGL programmer?

Answer (score 0):

Hey @ufunks I think you need some simulator.

Personally, i recommend you use the Gazebo simulation. For each of your tasks, you can use the following tutorials

- Loads a 3D model : http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=actor&cat=build_robot
- Change camera view/zoom : http://answers.ros.org/question/10342/programatically-set-the-camera-pose-in-gazebo-or-rviz/
- Recording : ffmpeg or some screen capture software

There're maybe other better simulator out there.